# problematic listing of folder with many files

Tags: ubuntu, ls

In ubuntu I have a folder that contains many (~10M) .txt files (around 1-2KB each). Folder is not big by itself (around 400MB) and does not contain subfolders, just the .txt files. I need to list it and do not succeed in doing so. (I can count the number of files, though, with `wc -l`) question is: is there a way to split the folder somehow or other way, without calling methods that `ls` uses?

Comment: Try: `for FILE in * ; do echo $FILE; done`

Comment: You write: "I need to list it and do not succeed in doing so." What have you tried? What error message (or other output) do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `find` to list the files:

```
find .
```

Using `*` or the like as a command argument is bound to give you an "Argument list too long" error, but it *may* work in a shell loop like suggested above by Andrew Stubbs.

If it doesn't, you can feed the `find` output from above to a `while` loop so you can process single files:

```
find . | while read filename; do
    dosomething $name
done
```

with appropriate values of "dosomething".

To "split" the folder, you can move the files to e.g. subdirectories based on their name, e.g. like this:

```
mkdir _a _b _c _d _e _f _g _h _i _j _k _l _m _n _o _p _q _r _s _t _u _v _w _x _y
find . | while read filename; do
    case $filename in
        a*) mv $filename _a;;
        b*) mv $filename _b;;
```

[...]

```
        z*) mv $filename _z;;
    esac
done
```

More sophisticated schemes are possible, of course.